# segmentation fault when using clock() function

Tags: c

My following code gives `segmentation fault: 11` only when I add the `clock()` function to calculate the time elapsed (When I comment clock(), I get results with no issues!!! ):

```
typedef struct heap_strct *Sort;
struct heap_strct {
    int count;
    int size;
    int *queue;
};

int main() {
    time_t start = clock();
    Sort h;   // Sort is a structure
    initi(h);
    parse(h);
    time_t end = clock();
    double time_elapsed = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Time = %f", time_elapsed);
}
```

I am using `#include <time.h>` but I don't know why such a fault appears! Kindly, can someone tell me why?

Comment: How do you know for sure?

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Because when I comment `clock()`, I get results

Comment: that may be very well outcome of UB.

Comment: [No, that's not why your program crashes](https://ideone.com/PGc0Zh)

Comment: Have you tried with `clock_t` as the function declaration of `clock()` specifies?

Comment: Post the definition of `Sort`, `initi` and `parse`

Comment: You are using the wrong type for `clock()` return value, it should be `clock_t` and not `time_t`. Apart from that your use of `clock()` is good.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — and then provide us with one.  What you're seeing is probably a consequence of undefined behaviour somewhere in either `initi()` or `parse()`.

Comment: You pass an uninitialized pointer to `initi()`, which has no way to set that pointer.  You then pass that (still) uninitialized pointer to `parse()`.  It is no wonder that your code crashes.  You probably need to revise `initi()`, either so that its interface is `void initi(Sort *h)` (called with `initi(&h);`) or so that its interface is `Sort *initi(void)` (called with `Sort h = initi();`).  See also [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — the short answer is "No".

Comment: "when I add X to my program, it starts crashing, therefore X is responsible for crashes" --- this looks like sound logic, but *it's not*.

Comment: Commenting out the part that you think is at fault, can be like trying to get bumps out of the carpet - you can displace the *effect* of the bug to somewhere else, perhaps where the harm is less immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an uninitialized pointer to function `initi()`. If this function modifies the structure, you invoke undefined behavior.

It is a very bad habit to hide pointers behind typedefs.  The comment is completely misleading: `Sort` is not a structure!

Define a structure directly and pass its address:

```
#include <time.h>

struct heap_strct {
    int count;
    int size;
    int *queue;
};

int main(void) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    struct heap_strct h;   // h is a structure for real now!
    initi(&h);
    parse(&h);
    time_t end = clock();
    double time_elapsed = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Time = %f\n", time_elapsed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed even the code comment `// Sort is a structure` was misleading.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie not true: the OP has `typedef struct heap_strct *Sort;`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. You were right. I remove pointer hiding and it worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` is a proven library function and will not cause a segfault.

You pass a pointer `h` to `initi` but there is no storage for `h` allocated. Then you pass the same pointer to `parse`. But there still is no storage for the structure!

When you comment `clock()` out, the call is not made so the stack is not changed. On the stack is also `h`, an uninitialized local variable.

Comment: `h` is not even a structure, it is a pointer!  this is so misleading!

Comment: @chqrlie, I see now. He had no storigae for `h`.